# How to use a 404 component in VUE3 single page app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I have the following structure of the code:

router.js:

```
  import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';

  const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'App',
      component: () => import('../../src/App.vue'),
    },
    {
      path: '/:pathMatch(.*)',
      name: 'ErrorView',
      component: () => import('../components/Error.vue'),
  }
  ],
});

export default router;
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <Land />
  <LeftNavbar />
  <Navbar />
  <Experience />
  <TechnologiesCarousel />
  <Projects />
  <Copyright />
  <BackToTop />
</template>
```

When I'm pressing in the URL bar: http://localhost:3000. The app is rendering properly which is fine, but when I'm trying to write a wrong URL, for eg: http://localhost:3000/abcf/ || http://localhost:3000/dsafbdmhgfjweghjfw to be redirected to the 404 page, I'm not redirected, the page still rendering the App.vue component.

Does anyone have any idea why the 404 page isn't rendered?

Answer (score 1):

Try like following `/:pathMatch(.*)*`:

```
{
  path: "/:pathMatch(.*)*",
  name: 'ErrorView',
  component: () => import('../components/Error.vue'),
},
```

and in App.vue place `<router-view />` and move components to other view.

Comment: Isn't working and I don't get any error.

Comment: @Gabriel hey mate, I corrected my answer, you need `<router-view />` in your app.vue

Comment: Hmm, If I'm putting that the '/' will be empty, since I have to remove my components.

Comment: That's ok, if you have same layout for the whole app. You can maybe place header and footer above and below <router-view /> and then create pages and routes for each of them

Comment: It's a single-page application.

Comment: It will still be single-page, by pages I mean views. Ohh now I think I got you , then your approach with layout view is fine I think

Comment: Yeah, I created a layout component with all components injected there.

Comment: Thanks for the <router-view /> tips.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using **Vue 3**.

In your router file you need to change the path to this:

```
  {
      path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*',
      name: 'ErrorView',
      component: () => import('../components/Error.vue'),
  }
```

---

For **Vue 2** the path can be: `path:'*'`

---

From **Vue 2 -> 3 migration** some more info for those they want to know what has changed:

Essentially, you should be able to replace the '*' path with '/:pathMatch(.*)*' and be good to go!

Reason: Vue Router doesn't use path-to-regexp anymore, instead it implements its own parsing system that allows route ranking and enables dynamic routing. Since we usually add one single catch-all route per project, there is no big benefit in supporting a special syntax for *.